# Abort: xxxx.bundle unknown bundle version 20

Tags: mercurial

I'm fairly new to using Mercurial, and green on Debian as well. I've been trying to unbundle this file for CCAT support in my EtherCAT Master.

```
wget https://github.com/Beckhoff/CCAT/raw/master/etherlab.bundle
hg unbundle etherlab.bundle
```

I get an error back

```
abort: etherlab.bundle: unknown bundle version 20
```

Does anyone know how to get around this? Or what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Mercurial in Debian 8 is too old to handle the bundle. Fortunately, the version available in Jessie backports can unbundle it.

You need to enable backports if you haven't already; as root:

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
apt-get update
```

Then upgrade Mercurial:

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install mercurial
```

Now you'll be able to unbundle the bundle you've downloaded.